# Secret dont create same password for database as it should be - terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Here create a random password:

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length  = 12  
  special = true
  override_special = "!#$%&*()-_=+[]{}:?"
}
```

Here I create a secret for the database:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "db_pass" {
  metadata {
    name = "db-pass"
  }
  data = {
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = "${aws_db_instance.database.password}"
    S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID : ""
    S3_SECRET_KEY : ""
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD     = "${var.rabbitpassw}"
    RABBITMQ_ERLANGCOOKIE = "${var.erlangcookie}"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_db_instance.database,
    module.s3_bucket
  ]
}
```

Then this code should use a random password that db uses to connect:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  allocated_storage       = var.instance_storage_db
  max_allocated_storage   = var.max_storage_db
  engine                  = var.instance_engine_db
  engine_version          = var.instance_engine_version_db
  instance_class          = var.instance_size_db
  identifier              = "${var.cluster_name}-db-instance"
  db_name                 = "tester"
  username                = "admin"
  password                = random_password.password.result
  snapshot_identifier     = var.db_snapshot_id
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.default.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.db_sg.id]
  skip_final_snapshot     = var.skip_final_snapshot_db
  multi_az                = var.multi_az_db
  backup_retention_period = var.ret_period_db
}
```

I I use it before, and it was working normally, now i create new cluster and secret create 24 character password, and i cannot connect to RDS it using mysql

When create hardcoded password, connections to RDS is normal

Same problem have with grafana random password.

Is anyone go true this problem?

Comment: You cannot connect to the DB from where?

Comment: @MarkoE from mysql docker image, that also make problem that pods can't connect to database, because password for RDS is not same as password in secret

Comment: There are not enough details to know the answer. Was the RDS instance in a public subnet and now the new one in private? Or was it always in the private, but the networking configuration changed? What is the command you are trying to use from the pod? It's unclear.

Comment: Its private database. I will give example
In 

`resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  password                = random_password.password.result`

If i set to:
`password                =  "examplepassword"`


Everithing will work fine.

But in:



`resource "kubernetes_secret" "db_pass" {
  metadata {
    name = "db-pass"
  }
  data = {
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = "${aws_db_instance.database.password}"`


This will create new random password, and it won't use "examplepassword" for password

Hope i explain somehow 

Thanks for help @MarkoE

Comment: I found problem, thank you very much for being here to help! <3 @MarkoE

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd use the `random_password.password.result` as data content for the kubernetes secret. You are creating a not necessary dependency.

When you create a hardcoded password (not recomended) or `random_password.password.result` inside a aws_db_instance resource, it works because it use the real content.

But remember that [kubernetes secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) content is offuscated with base64 format. So when you create a resource `kubernetes_secret` it's already generating the random_password with base64.

Anyway you can debug the content of your kubernetes secret and the random password.

**Debug**:

The output option from terraform is not allowed showing password even using sensitive = false , but if you has access to the plain text teraform.tfstate you could to find the plaint text of random password (something like `"result": "V1dp81Dxr#nj",`) and checking if it match with a similar query result of:

```
kubectl get secret db-pass -o jsonpath='{.data.MYSQL_PASSWORD}' -n namespace | base64 --decode | awk '{print $1}'
```

I hope that it help you.

Comment: Thank you @mrexojo , but problem here is that database create one password, and secret create another one. 
I can see password that secret create using 
'kubectl get secret db-password -o json' 

But 
'MYSQL_PASSWORD = "${aws_db_instance.database.password}"'
don't use created random password for database, look like create new one, and thats main problem.

Like i said, this was worked on last cluster, but now don't, i dont know is there any problem with update with terraform or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mrexojo, I found what's the problem.

I change from windows to linux OS, and i used  `kubectl get secret db-pass -o json`, while on windows i used `kubectl get secret db-pass -o json | jq '{name: .metadata.name,data: .data|map_values(@base64d)}'`
On windows work normaly, but on linux is deferent command

Thanks @MarkoE for help also, you are great!

right comand is `kubectl get secret db-pass -o jsonpath='{.data.MYSQL_PASSWORD}' -n namespace | base64 --decode | awk '{print $1}'`